# Internet not working with an AR8162

Tags: 12.04, internet

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop, but for some reason the Internet does not work.  The LAN works on windows 7 though.

My network card is atheros AR8162, also the option "Wired" does not appear in the Network window.  It also says "No Proprietary drivers are installed on your system"

I really need to get my LAN working so i can get the nvidia driver

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is where you will get the fix you might be looking for [from here](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/alx). That's the page for the `alx` driver. Here's an excerpt from the page:

> ***Description:***
>
> The alx driver is intended to only add support for newer Ethernet
>   device. It used to be the case that the alx driver was trying to
>   replace atl1c but aftter some discussions we deteremined its best to
>   keep doing evolutions on atl1c for older chipsets and only use alx for
>   newer chipset sthat previously did not have drivers. As it is right
>   now work is undergoing to remove all atl1c device support from the alx
>   driver, in the meantime the compat-wireless release has a temporary
>   patch from the original alx driver which removes the atl1c devices
>   from it.
>
> The alx driver will only provide support for:
>
> 1969:1091 - AR8161
>
> **1969:1090 - AR8162**
>
> ***Code:***
>
> This code has now been posted for inclusion upstream. If you want to
>   install this driver right now you can also do so by downloading this
>   tarball:
>
> http://www.orbit-lab.org/kernel/compat-wireless-2.6/2012/05/compat-wireless-2012-05-10-p.tar.bz2
>
> The `-p` postfix annotates that we have applied a patch in this
>   tarball from the `linux-next-pending/` directory. [For more details
>   see extra patches for compat-wireless documentation](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Download/stable/#Additional_patches_to_stable_releases).
>
> *To install:*
>
> To only compile and install the `alx` driver you can do:
>
> ```
> ./scripts/driver-select alx
>
> make
>
> sudo make install
> ```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. I will do the edit this time, but please do provide something more than just a link to the possible solution.

Comment: Suppose i have the driver file on the ubuntu desktop, pls give me the exact steps to install it..

Comment: no matter how much i try it shows "not a directory", "no such directory or file"

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with those drivers too. Here is my solution:

http://tuxilero.blogspot.cz/2013/09/how-to-atheros-ar8162-linux-drivers.html

Basicly you need instal ALX from compact drivers. But from kernel 3.10 there were some changes, so those drivers on the internet not work correctly for this atheros card. But driver in this link is patched. Quick step by step:

1. Download those drivers.

   ```
   wget -O- http://ge.tt/api/1/files/5b6OjGt/2/blob?download | tar -xz
   cd compat-drivers-3.9-rc4-2-su
   ```
2. Blacklist old drivers.

   ```
   sudo sh -c "echo \"blacklist atl1c\" > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ethernet.conf"
   ```
3. Select alx driver.

   ```
   ./scripts/driver-select alx
   ```
4. Compile and load!

   ```
   make

   sudo make install

   sudo make unload

   sudo modprobe alx
   ```
5. If not sure, reboot ;)